# Update table dynamically with server-sent events based on data from a promise in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have an async function that returns a promise of JSON values to display a table.  This works fine.  I would like to use server-sent events to update one column in the table, based values in the first set of data.

I am able to display the table and console log the `lastPrice` value from the SSEs, but cannot update the table dynamically with the data from the SSEs.

**Fetch code:**

```
async function getStocks() {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/equityPositions");
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    return json;
}

let promisePositions = getStocks();
```

**SSE code:**

```
const sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/sse');
sse.onmessage = function (event) {

    const jsonQuote = JSON.parse(event.data);
    let tickerSymbol = jsonQuote.symbol;
    let lastPrice = jsonQuote.last;
    lastPrices = {tickerSymbol: lastPrice}
    console.log("lastPrice=" + lastPrices[tickerSymbol]);
};
let lastPrices;
```

My table body looks like this (the values are nested in the JSON):

```
{#await promisePositions}
    <LoadingSpinner/>
{:then topLevels}
    {#each topLevels as topLevel}
        {#each Object.values(topLevel) as item}
            {#if item.symbol !== undefined}
                <tr>
                    <td>{item.symbol}</td>
                    <td><!--PRINT LAST PRICE HERE--></td>
                            <td>{topLevel.quantity}</td>
                </tr>
            {/if}
        {/each}
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p class="error">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

I tried using `{lastPrices[item.symbol]}` but that is undefined even though the log output prints the values.  It also seems that `<td>` tag doesn't accept `bind:` as a choice.  Is there an easy way to print the `lastPrice` for an `item.symbol` with Svelte?

I realize that I can update the DOM with JS directly (with `document.` syntax), but I understand that this is generally not best practice with Svelte.  I'm new to Svelte and a beginner with JS, but not to coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use svelte stores to handle async data everywhere in your code.

Below your async getStocks code wrapped in a store, with an initial value of null:

```
export const stockStore = readable(null, async (set) => {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/equityPositions");
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    set(json);  // update the store
    return () => {};
})
```

This way you can also create a priceStore;

Now it's easy to combine (the json data of) both stores using a derived store and loop reactive over the results using the $ prefix auto-subscription.